# Issue with Jackcess ExportFilter

Tags: java, ms-access, csv, jackcess

I found a great library called **Jackcess**, allows you to convert, parse create, etc with Microsoft Access.

The aim is to convert, which this code does successfully.

There is a **Filter functionality** upon export, this can be seen on the link to the documentation below. The aim is to use the **first 3 columns**, exclude the rest of the data.

[ExportUtil Documentation](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/ExportUtil.html#exportAll%28com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

Applying the filter object doesn't work, does anyone know if there's something else that needs to be ahcieved first... * scratching my head here *

[Export Filter Documentation](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/ExportFilter.html#filterColumns%28java.util.List%29)

```
public void db_dump(String mdbFile, String outputDir) {
    File file = new File("/Users/testUser/Downloads/example.mdb");
    if(file != null) {
    File outDir = new File("/Users/testUser/Desktop/output123");
    boolean success = outDir.mkdir();
        if (success) {
            Database db = null;
            try {
                db = DatabaseBuilder.open(file);
                Table t = db.getTable("MappedCHTCP");
                List<Column> cols  = new List<Column>() 
                    @Override methods for list ommited .... size(), contains(), etc
                System.out.println(t.getColumns());

//                  cols.add(0,t.getColumn("word"));

                 for (Column c : t.getColumns()) {
                      if((c != null) && (c.getColumnIndex() < 3)) {
                          System.out.println(c.getName());
                          cols.add(c);
                      }
                 }

                SimpleExportFilter ef = new SimpleExportFilter(); //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
                ef.filterColumns(cols);

                File csvFile = new File(outDir+File.separator+"MappedCHTCP.csv");
                ExportUtil.exportFile(db, "MappedCHTCP", csvFile, false, null, '"',ef); //NOT ABLE TO APPLY FILTER

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking... it's really strange! It doesn't matter weather you construct the object inside the `exportFile` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I found in the unit test code [here](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/xref-test/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ExportTest.html), the following sample code seems to work. It exports only the first three (3) columns of the table named [Members]:

```java
package jackcessTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ExportFilter;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ExportUtil;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.SimpleExportFilter;

public class JackcessTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(
                new File("C:/Users/Public/mdbTest.mdb"))) {

            ExportFilter eFilter = new SimpleExportFilter() {
                private List<Column> _cols = new ArrayList<Column>();
                private int _colIdx = 0;
                @Override
                public List<Column> filterColumns(List<Column> columns) {
                    for (Column c : columns) {
                        if (_colIdx++ < 3) _cols.add(c);
                    }
                    return _cols;
                }
            };

            ExportUtil.exportFile(
                    db, 
                    "Members", 
                    new File("C:/Users/Public/zzzJdump.csv"), 
                    true, 
                    ",", 
                    '"', 
                    eFilter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you ever so much! Not very clear is it :). Hopefully this will help someone in the future.